# get a returned value and a set of record in C# when calling a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that returns 2 output parameters and a record.

But in C#:

- `ExecuteReader` won't allow a returned value but allows records
- `ExecuteNonQuery` allows a returned value but not record.

How can I get both?

Comment: You are confusing `return value` and `output parameter`. For returning scalar data to the caller, you want the latter.

Comment: @KyleMit, Could you please spell out? In fact I am using Output parameter in my stored procedure (I thought it's called returned value too) Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output parameter returned by a stored procedure are not available until you close the DataReader.

Supposing you have

```
 SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  ...... do you record reading
 reader.Close();

 // Now the output parameters are available
 int result = (int)cmd.Parameters["OutputParameter1"].Value;
```

Of course this is supposing that you have correctly setup your output parameters....

This is from [SqlDataReader docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is
>   busy serving the SqlDataReader, and no other operations can be
>   performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it. This is the case
>   until the Close method of the SqlDataReader is called. For example,
>   you cannot retrieve output parameters until after you call Close.

Answer (score 1):

All sql server stored procedure return an `int` return code. By default, it is 0 if no `return` statement is executed all, or a simple `return` with no value is executed. Otherwise, the return code is set to the value specified on the `return` statement (such as `return @someIntegerValue`. This return code is accessible in C# by adding a parameter to the command's parameter's collection with its `Direction` property set to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`.

You can also return a value by using an `output` parameter.

This code should do you. It shows how to access both an `output` parameter and the procedure's `int` return code. I'm pouring the results set(s) into a `DataSet`... but opening a `SqlDataReader` will work just the same, though you won't be able to access any output parameters or the stored procedure's return code until the `DataReader` has finished consuming the results and finalized command execution.

```cs
static DataSet execSomeStoredProc( string tableName, out int columns , out DateTime? dtCreated )
{
  const string connectString = @"Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ;

  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

  using ( SqlConnection session  = new SqlConnection(connectString) )
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd      = session.CreateCommand() )
  using ( SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
  {

    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.my_simple_stored_procedure" ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // a simple input parameter
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@tableName" , tableName ) ;

    // an output-only parameter
    SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter( "@creationDate" , SqlDbType.DateTime , 8 ) ;
    outputParameter.ParameterName = "@creationDate" ;
    outputParameter.Direction    = ParameterDirection.Output;
    outputParameter.IsNullable   = true ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add( outputParameter ) ;

    // the integer return code that all stored procedure returns.
    // The default value of 0 is return if no return statement is executed, or
    // a return statement with no value is executed.
    SqlParameter rc = new SqlParameter("@rc" ,SqlDbType.Int ) ;
    rc.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add( rc ) ;

    session.Open();
    adapter.Fill(ds) ;
    session.Close() ;

    columns = (int) rc.Value ;
    dtCreated = outputParameter.Value == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime)outputParameter.Value ;

  }

  return ds ;
}
```

The above code, for what it's worth, is executing this stored procedure:

```sql
create procedure dbo.my_simple_stored_procedure

  @tableName   varchar(255) ,
  @creationDate datetime output

as

  set ansi_nulls              on
  set concat_null_yields_null on
  set nocount                 on

  declare @create_date datetime
  declare @rows        int

  select *
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
  where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    and c.TABLE_NAME = @tableName
  order by c.TABLE_CATALOG ,
           c.TABLE_SCHEMA  ,
           c.TABLE_NAME    ,
           c.ORDINAL_POSITION

  set @rows = @@rowcount

  select @create_date = st.create_date
  from sys.tables st
  where st.object_id = object_id( 'dbo.'+@tableName )

  set @creationDate = @create_date

  return @rows
go
```

Comment: Thank you Nicholas. Both your solution and Steve`s solution worked for me :)